# PrintWriter doesn't save all characters

Tags: java, file, input, output, printwriter

```
class Start 
{
    File plikIN;
    Scanner in;
    PrintWriter out;

    Start(String input, String output)
    {
        plikIN = new File(input);
        try{
        in = new Scanner(plikIN);
        out = new PrintWriter(output);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {System.out.println("Nie odnaleziono podanego pliku\n"+e);}
    }

    private void saveing() throws IOException
    {
        String word;
        int wordLength;
        String wordTable[];
        char c;

        while((word = in.next()) != null)
        {
            wordLength = word.length();
            wordTable = new String[wordLength];
            for(int k=0; k<wordTable.length; ++k)
            {
                c = word.charAt(k); 
                out.println(c);
            }   
        }
        out.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String nazwaPlikuWejsciowego = args[0];
        String nazwaPlikuWyjsciowego = args[1];
        Start doit = new Start(nazwaPlikuWejsciowego, nazwaPlikuWyjsciowego);
        doit.saveing();

    }
}
```

My problem is saving to file. After the `saveing` method above, the file does not contain any single character. When I move the `out.close()` to `while` for instance, the file contains one word. When `out.close()` is in `for`, the program saves one character only. Why?

Comment: Your loop `while((word = in.next())` will throw an error, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `out.flush()` before `out.close()`.

You need to flush the bytes to disk before you close it..

Comment: That and also, id use try{ }catch(){}finally //close resources

Comment: According to the javadoc of `close`: `Closes the stream, flushing it first`. So calling `flush` first is nothing more than cargo-cult. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/Writer.java.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Answer (score 0):

This `((word = in.next()) != null)` will throw an exception.
`in.next()` doesn't return null when there are no more elements. Take a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())